# How to set the color of all parts of the background in a stacked bar chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Here is the code for the current state of the tug-of-war between England and Scotland:

```
public TugOfWar(String s) {
    super(s);

    // data set
    DefaultKeyedValues2DDataset dataset = new DefaultKeyedValues2DDataset();
    dataset.addValue(0.2, "England", "");
    dataset.addValue(0.8, "Scotland", "");

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart("tug-of-war",
        "", "", dataset, PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, true, false, false);
    CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();

    // customize axis
    SymbolAxis axis = new SymbolAxis("", new String[]{
            "England", "draw", "Scotland"});
    axis.setRange(0, 2d);
    plot.setRangeAxis(axis);

    // customize renderer
    BarRenderer renderer = new StackedBarRenderer();
    renderer.setBase(0.8);
    renderer.setMinimumBarLength(0);
    renderer.setMaximumBarWidth(0.5);
    renderer.setItemMargin(0.0);
    renderer.setDrawBarOutline(true);
    renderer.setShadowVisible(true);
    renderer.setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());
    plot.setRenderer(renderer);

    // customize background
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.lightGray);
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.lightGray);
    plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
    plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);

    ChartPanel chartpanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    chartpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 270));
    setContentPane(chartpanel);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    TugOfWar tugOfWar = new TugOfWar("Tug of war");
    tugOfWar.pack();
    RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(tugOfWar);
    tugOfWar.setVisible(true);
}
```

Which leads us to this:

[image]

As you can see, the center of the plot's background has been set to *white* (correct), but the left and right margin are still *light grey*. How does one set the color of the outer parts of the background ?

Comment: Dumb question... what happens if you do `chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);` instead of `plot.`

Comment: @durron597 `chart.setBackgroundPaint` controls the color of the background *around* the chart, meanwhile `plot.setBackgroundPaint` controls the color of the background *in* the chart. All of the background ? No, not all of it ... as it seems ;)

Comment: What about `setInsets`? Edit: i'm trying to help you just by looking at the javadoc, I can't easily test anything myself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alternating background is a feature of `SymbolAxis`, which you can disable.

```
axis.setGridBandsVisible(false);
```

[image]

Comment: A similar example seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73431254/230513).